# Angular 5, Use PlatformLocation to get query parameters from URL (without router)?

Tags: angular, parameters, location

How I get the query parameters from URL in Angular5?

a link to my web page, just like:
**http://localhost:4200/index.html?action=show-news&type=1**

I want to get them in my service...

---

In Angualr1.x, I can get query parameters from $location, just like:

```
var searchObject = $location.search();
```

In Angular5, I can get them from PlatformLocation, just like:

```
this.platformLocation.search
```

But in documents:
PlatformLocation -- '**This class should not be used directly by an application developer. Instead, use Location.**'

In Class Location, I cannot find any solution to get the query parameters.

---

Someone said get them from Class ActivatedRoute, just like:

```
this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
  console.log('this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap: ', this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap);
});
```

But it cannot get them ...

What can I do? Use Class PlatformLocation directly?

Answer (score 0):

You have to inject ActivatedRoute:

```
private _queryParams;

constructor(
  private readonly _router: Router,
  private readonly _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
)

ngOnInit() {
    this.assignQueryParams();
    this._router.events
     .takeUntil(this._destroy$)
     .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
     .subscribe(() => this.assignQueryParams());
}

private assignQueryParams() {
  this._queryParams = this._activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams;
}
```

And then by getting the state of _activatedRoute on initialization and on router change, you always have a reference to the current queryParams in your component!

Comment: I want to get them in service, not in component. I just want to get 'action' in parameters, then show different component by different 'action'.